# Tool for analyzing .Net app memory dumps

Tags: .net, memory-dump, postmortem-debugging

Can somebody suggest a good **free** tool for analyzing .Net memory dumps other than Adplus/windbg/sos ?

Comment: What is wrong with windbg? What are the apps you mentioned missing that you looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [load sos](http://blogs.msdn.com/vijaysk/archive/2007/11/15/sos-your-visual-studio.aspx) and your memory dump into Visual Studio to at least insulate you from the 'interesting' ui that WinDbg presents.

Answer (score 5):

You can try out [DebugDiag 1.1](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/05/21/debugdiag-1-1-or-windbg-which-one-should-i-use-and-how-do-i-gather-memory-dumps.aspx)

Comment: If we're talking about tools then I completely agree here. This is the only TOOL for analysis. It can be really helpful for memory dump investigation. This tool showed me clearly wcf connection leak in my situation. It'd took much more time to find such a problem with pure windbg+sos+psscor+etc. There's v.1.2 already: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798

Answer (score 4):

I found [MemoScope.Net](https://github.com/fremag/MemoScope.Net) - an excellent GUI for WinDbg and ClrMd.

Comment: The AppVeyor links on here don't work for me - but easy enough to just clone the repo and build it. Was worth it in my case - showed me exactly where my memory leak was

Comment: @AHowgego github repos often have releases associated with them: https://github.com/fremag/MemoScope.Net/releases

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [SOS Assist](http://www.thinktecture.com/sosassist), it provides a GUI around SOS.

Comment: This tool looks dead. Download link doesn't work on their page.

Answer (score 2):

I fully recommend .Net Memory Profiler.
Beside being a great live memory profiler for .Net applications, it can also load memory dumps, and let you traverse the objects in the dump in a very intuitive an easy way.

Opening big dump (> 1 GB) can take a few hours though, but for us it's worth the wait.
I don't know if they have trial version, but if they do you should definitely give them a shot.

Comment: You're right - didn't notice it was a requirement. But it is still the best mem-profiler I ever used.

Answer (score 1):

You could give a look at sosnet which is small opensource winforms application which wraps windbg/sos.

https://bitbucket.org/grozeille/sosnet

It's handy and straight forward to use.

Please try it out, and contribute to it by submitting ideas / patches